# Can't import python libraries with Crontab

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to run my python scripts with Crontab.
The problem is I can't import the libraries.
I tried with three different crontab lines:

```
 * */1 * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/clientes_us.py
 * */1 * * * python /Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/clientes_us.py
 * */1 * * * /usr/bin/python /Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/clientes_us.py
```

I received an email with:

```
Subject: Cron <martinbouhier@ops-mac> python /Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/clientes_ar.py
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=martinbouhier>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=martinbouhier>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/martinbouhier>
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 11:12:01 -0300 (-03)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/clientes_ar.py", line 10, in <module>
    from Modulos_epl.logins_us_ar import (
  File "/Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/Modulos_epl/logins_us_ar.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Comment: do you use virtualenv?

Comment: No! I'm not working with virtualenv

Comment: Well, there's your problem.

Comment: why? I don't create a virtualenv and the libraries are in the default python folder. @DanielRoseman

Comment: But *whose* "default Python folder"?

Comment: I mean all libraries I'm installin with pip install "library" so I have all my libraries in "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python". Why I need to create a virtualenv? I can run a simple script with one line as "print 'Daniel' but can't with an installed library?? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes, *you* do that. But the cron is not running as you.

Comment: Okey so... can you share how I should write the line on crontab -e please? @DanielRoseman

Comment: I solved it: `* */1 * * * /usr/local/bin/python /Users/martinbouhier/Desktop/Github/klipfolio/Scripts/clientes_us.py` @DanielRoseman